# Blue Badge with sprint name

Tags: youtrack

I've created a project using the Scrum template and don't change the default configuration. I have some issues in the backlog with the Epic->User Story->Task hierarchy. User Stories are displayed as swimlanes and I move a User Story to the board and It stays in the backlog with a nice blue badge with Sprint name.

[Just like the one in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIBO7.png)

But then I move another User Story to the board and it just disappears from the backlog. At first glance, both User Stories look the same, so I can't figure out what it depends on. Could you give me a hand with that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To help you find out why it happens, I need to take a look at the board settings and issue's properties. So please share the following details:

- a screenshot of the board settings (General, Columns and Swimlanes)
- a screenshot of the issue page that disappears

You can send the details to Youtrack support directly at https://youtrack-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: Thank you, Sergey. I've written to [Youtrack support directly](https://youtrack-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/2733120). Waiting for the reply.